# Sorting a column in ascending and descending order depending on the current date

Tags: mysql, date

Please help. Here my mySQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`products`)
ORDER BY (
CASE WHEN `ExpiredDate` > NOW() 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) DESC , `ExpiredDate` ASC
```

I'm going to sort the array result as the available products like this:

```
12-10-2013
12-15-2013
12-28-2013
12-09-2013 -- Today
12-08-2013
12-04-2013
12-01-2013
```

But the current result is now the expired products is order by ascending like this:

```
12-10-2013
12-15-2013
12-28-2013
12-09-2013 -- Today
12-01-2013
12-04-2013
12-08-2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM products
ORDER BY ExpiredDate < NOW(), ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, expiredDate, NOW()))
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb1bc/1.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use following query instead of yours,

SELECT * 
FROM (`products`)
ORDER BY (
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ExpiredDate,'%Y-%m-%d') >  NOW() 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) DESC , `ExpiredDate` ASC

More details can be found at
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/